# What is the conversion rate from USD to Nintendo Points?

Tags: nintendo-ds

I was looking at the DS games on the eShop, and they were priced as real money. Just to be curious, is there a conversion between Nintendo points and money? (USD)

Comment: Nintendo points?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of USD to Nintendo Points are set by Nintendo, so there are no "fixed" prices.

As of June 15, 2016, 2000 Nintendo Points costs $19.99 USD, so the value is currently 1¢ USD = 1 Nintendo Point.